# What is causing this code to repaint itself?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

In the code below, the arrow keys are used to draw a line as in etch-a-sketch (but you have to resize the window first to trigger the panel's focus request at the right time -- that's a question for a different time, perhaps). The graphics command g.drawLine() occurs in the keyPressed() function, repaint() is not called explicitly, but the image updates itself as the arrow keys are pressed.  Why is that?  All the documentation I have looked at only talks about the JPanel automatically repainting itself when it is resized or uncovered.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Etch extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
    public int xPrev, yPrev, xNew, yNew, inc;

    public Etch(int start){
        xPrev = start;
        yPrev = start;
        xNew = start;
        yNew = start;
        inc = 10;
        addKeyListener(this);


    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame w = new JFrame("Keyboard");
        w.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Etch panel = new Etch(200);
        panel.setFocusable(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        Container c = w.getContentPane();
        c.add(panel);

        w.setResizable(true);
        w.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int code = e.getKeyCode();


        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            xPrev = xNew;
            yPrev = yNew;
            yNew -= inc;

        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            xPrev = xNew;
            yPrev = yNew;
            yNew += inc;

        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            xPrev = xNew;
            yPrev = yNew;
            xNew -= inc;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            xPrev = xNew;
            yPrev = yNew;
            xNew += inc;
        }

        Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawLine(xPrev, yPrev, xNew, yNew);
    }

    // Not used but required by the KeyListener interface
    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e) { }

    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e) { }
}
```

Comment: `this.requestFocusInWindow();` is a bad idea within the `paintComponent` method.  Painting should paint the current state and never change the state of the component

Answer (score 2):

- `this.requestFocusInWindow();` is a bad idea within the `paintComponent` method.  Painting should paint the current state and never change the state of the component
- `getGraphics` is not how painting is done in Swing.  Custom painting should be done from within the context of the `paintComponent` method. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details
- Consider using key bindings over `KeyListener`, as you can control the focus level required to trigger the key events.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Remember, you don't control the paint process in Swing, a paint cycle can be triggered by any number of events, most of which you don't actually control.  Try working within the process instead of out of it.

Start by creating a `List` of `java.awt.Point`.  Add each point to the `List` when a key event occurs.  Use the `paintComponent` to iterate over the `List` and paint the lines between the `Point`s...

Comment: Thanks for the comments about how to improve the code.  Given that the code I posted is not a good way of accomplishing its purpose, I am still puzzled about how it is actually working, i.e. what is causing the screen image to be updated after every arrow-key event.  Does any change to the graphics object cause the screen to be repainted?  That seemed unlikely to me, as did the idea that the screen is repainted every time a key is pressed.

Comment: It was working because Swing uses a passive painting alrogtihim, that is, your paintComponent method will only be called when the RepaintManager thinks it needs to be. This allows you to use getGraphics to paint to the last known result of a paint cycle, it's also the reason why it was wiped clean when paintComponent was called again. Painting should be done within the confines of the paintComponent method, this way, you know when the screen needs to be updated. Your key events should call repaint to make a request that the UI be updated